# Writing applescripts to Find & Replace text in an Excel Spreadsheet/Word Document, according to a 2-column Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, macos, replace, ms-word, applescript

I have a master Excel spreadsheet. ColumnA lists words & phrases; ColumnB lists their abbreviations.

I'd like to write an applescript to Find & Replace ColumnA with ColumnB within Word documents and also in another Excel spreadsheet.

I found the applescript below, which works reasonably well at Finding & Replacing in Word documents.

1. It could be improved if I can figure out a way to use wildcards so I don't have to populate ColumnA with all tenses, singular and plural, etc…
2. Also, I'd like to find    (two spaces) and replace them with   (a single space). I'd like to loop this repeatedly until there are no more instances of double-spaces.

This applescript opens an Excel spreadsheet and copies its *used range* into a list of value pairs comprised of the *find* and *replacement* strings. The script then loops through all entries in the list and performs a series of find/replace in the Word document.

3. When I alter the applescript below to replace `tell application "Microsoft Word"` with `tell application "Microsoft Excel"` and `open file theDOCX` with `open file theXLSX`, I encounter this syntax error when I run the script: "Expected end of line, etc. but found class name." How can I resolve this error.

```
use scripting additions
set theXLSX to (choose file of type ("org.openxmlformats.spreadsheetml.sheet"))
set theDOCX to (choose file of type {"org.openxmlformats.wordprocessingml.document"})

tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    activate
    open file theXLSX
    tell active sheet of document 1
    -- create a list of lists where each row will become a two component ¬
        list item comprised of the find string and the replace string  
    set arange to value of used range 
    end tell
end tell

tell application "Microsoft Word"
    activate
    open file theDOCX
    set myfind to find object of text object of active document
    set properties of myfind to {match case:false, match whole word:true, match wildcards:false}
    
    repeat with arow in arange
        execute find myfind find text (item 1 of arow) replace with (item 2 of arow) replace replace all
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Have you tried the find() function? or substitute() ? both in excel. also to replace 2 spaces with one there is trim().

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the error messages, the `choose file` command produces an *alias* which is not what Office's *open* command expects. Combining it with *file* (eg open file theXLSX) compounds the problem.

```
choose file of type "org.openxmlformats.wordprocessingml.document"
    --> alias "MacHD:Users:username:Desktop:wabbr.docx"

open file theDOCX
    --> Microsoft Word got an error: file (alias "MacHD:Users:username:Desktop:wabbr.docx") doesn’t understand the “open” message.
```

So get the reference as text instead, like so:

```
choose file of type "org.openxmlformats.wordprocessingml.document")) as text
    --> "MacHD:Users:username:Desktop:wabbr.docx"

open theDOCX
    --> open "MacHD:Users:username:Desktop:wabbr.docx"
```

Also, if your abbreviations file stays the same, you don't need to choose it each time. You can just set it directly, like so, and then you will only need to choose the correct word file.

```
set theXLSX to "MacHD:Users:username:Desktop:xabbr.xlsx"
```

---

Here is a script that should do what you need, based on my understanding of that.

```
use scripting additions
set tx to (choose file of type ("org.openxmlformats.spreadsheetml.sheet")) as text
    --> "MacHD:Users:username:Desktop:xabbr.xlsx"
set tw to (choose file of type {"org.openxmlformats.wordprocessingml.document"}) as text
    --> "MacHD:Users:username:Desktop:wabbr.docx"

tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    set wbx to open workbook workbook file name tx
    
    tell active sheet of wbx
        set ur2 to intersect range1 (get used range) range2 column "A:B"
        set wordPairList to value of ur2
    end tell
end tell


tell application "Microsoft Word"
    activate
    open tw
    set nw to name of front document
    
    set myf to find object of text object of active document
    set properties of myf to {match case:false, match whole word:true, match wildcards:false, match all word forms:true}
    
    repeat with eaSearch in wordPairList
        execute find myf find text (item 1 of eaSearch) replace with (item 2 of eaSearch) replace replace all
    end repeat
    execute find find object of text object of active document find text ".." replace with "." replace replace all
    execute find find object of text object of active document find text " ^w" replace with space replace replace all
end tell
```

#### Notes:

- Excel has the `open workbook` command so I use that instead. It allows you to assign the resulting workbook object to a variable, which means you don't need to rely on whichever is the front document to control which document you are working with.
- I find that *used range* is erratic so I limit it using the `intersect` command.
- Note the properties used in configuring the find object.

  - *match wildcards* can be set to *true* and then you can use any of the standard wildcard offerings of word.
  - That said, there is also a *match all word forms* option which should do what you want as it finds different forms of words, for example, if it is set to true, then a search for 'guarantee' will also find 'guarantees' and 'guaranteed'. I would recommend setting that to true and *match wildcards* to false and testing this combination to see if it meets your needs.
- I added two additional searches outside the repeat loop:

  - When you replace a term with an abbreviation that ends with a period, you can get problematic results if the word is found at the end of a sentence as you will then get a double period (ie `..`).
    For example: `the guarantee.` becomes `the guar..`
    So one search will find `..` and replace them with a single period `.`.
  - Second, I added a search that uses a *special character* (^w) which stands for *white space*, which can be a single space or a run of consecutive spaces. To prevent it from pointlessly replacing every individual space, I include a single space with it. So it will search for any run of 2+ spaces and replace them with a single space. This allows you to make all such replacements in a single pass.

Finally, on a separate note, while I think your approach should work well, you might also consider using a csv (or tsv) text file to store your replacement word pairs. The advantages would be that you could open the file in a text editor or in excel, and you could also read and manipulate it directly using applescript or shell commands.